# Router not displaying correct URL in Django RestFramework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

This is how I defined urls.py file of my app

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('hello-viewset', views.HelloViewSet, base_name='hello-viewset')
router.register('profiles', views.UserProfileViewSet)
router.register('schema', views.SchemaViewSet)
router.register('creddefination', views.CredDefViewSet)
router.register('overalltable', views.OverallViewSet)



urlpatterns = [

    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

urls.py of Project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('DIAPI.urls')),

]
```

[image: THis is my base API view]
I am not getting correct address for creddefination. But when i manually go to http://127.0.0.1:7000/api/creddefination/ it is working. It is just not displaying correctly. What might be reason  for this

Comment: what does "not displaying correctly" mean ? Traceback ? empty list ? results with unexpected fields/values ?

Comment: as you can see in the image attached, in creddefination it is showing different address. When i comment out the part for overalltable, It is displaying correctly in UI.

Comment: My bad, I did not understand it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `views.CredDefViewSet` and `views.OverallViewSet` are using the same model.

If that's true, then the default `register`'s `basename` will be named after that model and used as name in a call to Django's `reverse` url construction. Since the API Root view will be trying to resolve both views with the same name, it'll lead to the same url.

Workaround is to explicitly add a `basename` to one of the view:

```
router.register('creddefination', views.CredDefViewSet, basename='creddeef')
```

Comment: yes, they are both using the same model. I will try this in morning.